# searchView menuItem appears in the collapsible menu then disappears

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

My current situation is as so:

My SearchView appears on the menu.

[image: My SearchView appears on the menu.]

Normally the collapsible menu does not have the menu for search.

[image: Normally the collapsible menu does not have the menu for search.]

When I press the search menu and open the collapsible menu there is Search in the collapsible menu. Why does this happen?

[image: When I press the search menu and open the collapsible menu there is Search in the collapsible menu.]

Also, after this happens, if the collapsible menu is closed and the user exits the search, the search icon disappears.
How can I resolve the issue?

[image: Search Icon is no longer there!]

My onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)

        val trendingBtn = menu?.findItem(R.id.trending)
        trendingBtn?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            viewModel.trending()
            true
        }


        val searchItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.search)
        val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView

        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
            override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Search is Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return true
            }

            override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Search is Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return true
            }
        })

        searchView.queryHint = "Search"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(s: String?): Boolean {
                val searchString = "Searching " + s
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, searchString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                loadSearchVideoList(s)

                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, s)
                intent.putExtra(
                    "CUSTOM_MESSAGE",
                    "you can also add custom message when submitting the search action"
                )
                intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEARCH
                startActivity(intent)
                return false
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

My menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
        android:title="@string/trending"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_trending_up_24"
        android:id="@+id/trending"/>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [invalidateOptionsManu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) method, I guess is what you are looking for.

You should call this method after the search is expanded so it can "re-create" the menu.

From doc :

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed.

Comment: Big thanks! Sorry if this was a beginner-level question.  I'm new to android development!
Since I had both search expand and search collapse, the invalidateOptionsMenu() was need under search collapse as well.